# lldb regex that includes a file path

Tags: regex, nsstring, escaping, lldb

I am trying to write an lldb alias that writes an image to a file.  The following works, but there is a problem:

```
command regex logImageFile 's/(.+) (.+)/ expr (int) [ (id)UIImagePNGRepresentation(%1) writeToFile: @"%2.png" atomically: YES ]/'
```

The problem is that I have to enter the full path every time.  It would be much better for me to have a directory that it always uses.  So I tried this:

```
command regex logImageFile 's/(.+) (.+)/ expr (int) [ (id)UIImagePNGRepresentation(%1) writeToFile: @"/users/myUsername/Desktop/tempImages/%2.png" atomically: YES ]/'
```

Now, when I enter something like the following in the Xcode console, lldb always says that logImageFile is not a valid command.

```
logImageFile fooImage barFile
```

The problem is likely the slashes inside the path.  I assume I have to escape them somehow, but how?  Note that what I have is an NSString inside an lldb regex -- but I don't know what flavor of regex that actually is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using the `/` character to separate the parts of your regular expression and that character also appears in your substitution text in the file path.  The easiest fix is to use a different separator.  The `s///` format is the most common but you can use `s###` just as easily.  e.g.

```
(lldb) command regex logImageFile 's#(.+) (.+)#expr (int) puts("[ (id)UIImagePNGRepresentation(%1) writeToFile: @\"/users/myUsername/Desktop/tempImages/%2.png\" atomically: YES ]")#'
(lldb) logImageFile fooImage barFile
(int) $1 = 10
[ (id)UIImagePNGRepresentation(fooImage) writeToFile: @"/users/myUsername/Desktop/tempImages/barFile.png" atomically: YES ]
```

I told `expr` that the return type was `(int)` here so it is printing that (assigning it to convenience variable `$1`) - but if you'd used `(void)`, it would have avoided printing anything.

I'm using `puts()` here instead of the real call that you're trying to set up - but I think I spotted the problem with your original regular expression command alias.  Give this a try.

Comment: Such an easy solution, I don't know how long I've been trying to get around this.